# Conditional breakpoint modifier to see if array has changed

Tags: c++, debugging, breakpoints

I was playing with the variable changes breakpoint modifier in Visual Studio 2012. From my understanding, the variable change modifier causes the debugger to break if the specified variable value changes from a previous location execution. I think that this would be useful in narrowing down memory overwrites. My very simple C++ code is this:

```
int main ()
{
    printf("This program converts upper case chars to lower and vice versa\n");

    char str[20]="lowercase";;

    int i;

    for (i=0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122)
        {
            str[i]-=32;
        }
        else
        {
            str[i]+=32;
        }
    }

    str[1] = 'o';
    printf("%s\n",str);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Now I set conditional breakpoint on two lines

- `str[i]=str[i]-32`
- `printf("%s\n", str)`

to hit when array `str` changes. To do this I set a location breakpoint, then select "condition" on right clicking and in the condition textbox I put str,20. Finally I select the "has changed" radio button.

Now what I'm seeing is this:

The breakpoint is hit everytime on the line `str[i]-=32`, but never on the line `printf("%s\n", str)` and I'm curious as to why. Obviously the array has changed because of the line preceding the `printf` statement, so why isn't the breakpoint hit?

What am I missing here?

Comment: printf does not modify the value of a var, so the breakpoint is never hit.

Comment: `str` never changes, only its contents do.

Answer (score 1):

You are only breaking when that memory is written, not read. The function printf only reads that memory.